# How to display the a line of text in li tag in Django template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have text saved in my mysql records which looks like this:

```
Handmade item

Materials: wooden handcrafted handle, professional laser engraved rubber, brown 
cardboard special gift box, authorial stamp passport
```

the text above is represent overview in my accessory model which is:

```
from django.db import models

class Accessory(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='accessories/', default='accessories/no.png')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    img_inside1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='accessories/', default='accessories/no.png', blank=True)
    img_inside2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='accessories/', default='accessories/no.png', blank=True)
    img_inside3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='accessories/', default='accessories/no.png', blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    overview = models.TextField(blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
```

I want to display each line in `<li>` tag

to appear like that:

```
                 <ul>
                    <li><p>Handmade item</p></li>
                    <li><p>Materials: wooden handcrafted handle, 
                       professional laser engraved rubber, brown cardboard 
                      special gift box, authorial stamp passport</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

using `linebreaks` filter will not apply `<ul>` default style (showing bullets). thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is python Code?

Comment: here is the model related to accessory

`from django.db import models


class Accessory(models.Model):
    overview = models.TextField(blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()





 
`

Comment: please put this python code in question

Comment: i have added my python code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick and dirty solution:**  split the string on newlines and iterate over the result.

```
class Accessory(models.Model):
    # ...
    overview = models.TextField()

    def overview_lines(self):
        return filter(None, (line.strip() for line in self.overview.splitlines()))
```

and then

```
             <ul>
                {% for line in howeryounamedyourobject.overview_lines %}                    
                <li><p>{{ line }}</p></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
```

**Better solutions:**

either have a proper model for materials (whit a many to many relationship) or use markup instead of plain text in your "overview" field.